How can I set the value for interactive grid columns before insert dynamic?
How can I set the value for columns in interactive grid before Insert its hidden items and I need to set the value automatically before insert .
I created process and set the following values
:HOSPITAL_NO := :P0_HOSPITAL_NO;
:CREATING_DATE := SYSDATE;
:CREATING_USER := :P0_USERNAME;
:USER_ID := :P33_USERNAME;

I put the process first one in the processes before Save interactive grid data process
but when I click on save button it show error
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("A244864"."SYS_CLINIC_USERS"."HOSPITAL_NO")

Is this way correct to set the columns value ?

There is not enough information in your question so indicate what is wrong but here is an example. It could guide you in the right direction. This is on the EMP/DEPT sample data set
create editable IG

Region name "Emp 2"
Source query: SELECT empno, ename, sal FROM emp
Primary key column EMPNO

create custom process

Code: :SAL := :SAL + 1
Set this to run BEFORE the Automatic Row Processing process
Set "Editable Region" to "Emp 2"
Set Execution Scope to "For Created and Modified Rows"

Now when changing a row and click save, notice that the SAL column value is increased by 1.

Thank you its working the missing was   Set "Editable Region" to "Emp 2"

Yup that explains. If that is not there the context of the IG is missing and the column bind variables don't exist. It will also be executed only once and not for each row.
